# Broken example in Google Drive SDK quick start documentation

Tags: java, maven, google-drive-api

I need to develop an application that would be able to download a given document from Google Drive. I have found out that the recommended technology to use in the Java world is currently [the Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

As described by [the quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java) I have imported the required dependencies to my Maven project like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev98-1.17.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

The official sample `DriveCommandLine` source code (to be found at the bottom of same page) refuses to compile with the following error messages:

- `The import com.google.api.client.json.jackson cannot be resolved` (at `DriveCommandLine.java`, line 8),
- `JacksonFactory cannot be resolved to a type` (at `DriveCommandLine.java`, line 27).

How do I fix it? I'm running Java version 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to import the following dependency as well in order for the code to work. It contains the `JacksonFactory` class.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```